# How to remove a column in group_by statement?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
ucla_all = ucla_all.rename(columns={'OUTSTANDING':'% Reimbursed'})
ucla_group = ucla_all.groupby(['CDS Code'])
data = pd.DataFrame(ucla_group.apply(lambda x: ((x['% Reimbursed'] != 0).value_counts(normalize=True) * 100)))
data = data.unstack().reset_index
data
```

and this table:

```
<bound method DataFrame.reset_index of          % Reimbursed            
                False       True 
CDS Code                         
2110        20.312500   79.687500
2111        13.492063   86.507937
2220        12.861953   87.138047
2221        24.734982   75.265018
2231        18.965517   81.034483
```

What would be the best way to remove the `False` column?

Comment: BTW, your `data` is not a `DataFrame`, but a method `reset_index`, since you didn't _call_ but assigned in the second last line (add `()` to `...reset_index`). As for the actual problem, just use `data.drop('False', 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Add `()` because [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method:

```
data = data.unstack().reset_index()
```

And then remove boolean column `False` without `''` by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
data = data.drop(False, axis=1)
```